# Should the badge design for this site be changed?

Tags: discussion, badges

So, I have seen each stack exchange sites have their own stylized badge style. For example CrossValidated has a leaf like symbol, Biology has a genetic symbol. It definitely helps to add uniqueness to the site. Someone pointed out few benefits of having customized badges on Stackoverflow. I cannot find the link now. So should we have a new badge (something like a robot or a brain)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This site is currently in beta. Beta sites do not normally have custom design elements.

Furthermore, [Stack Exchange are ch-ch-ch-changing](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/307862/ch-ch-ch-changes-left-nav-responsive-design-themes) their approach to site design, and as a part of that, badges will be standardized: one badge design to rule them all.

> Standardized items will include:
>
> - Navigation
> - Fonts
> - Buttons/Icons
> - Badges
> - Tags
> - Newsletter ads